# using variable as key to access property from a file in maven

Tags: maven, variables, properties-file

I am reading properties from a file in maven...

<’file’>${workspace.basedir}/deployment/pod.properties<’/file’>

(ignore the quotes in tag, its a normal xml tag)

which has following properties...

```
dev-service=Dev-Service-PoD
qa-service=QA-Service-PoD
```

when I run a build for a module dev-service I want to get the property assigned to this module.
<’podname’>${dev-service}<'/podname’>

but the problem is I don’t want to hard code the module name to retrieve the pod.name from property file.

I want to use the module property ${project.artifactId} (which evaluates to dev-service) to retrieve its respective property, 
so that value of each module can be retrieve runtime dynamically

The value of ${project.artifactId} should be passed as key to access the property from file

something like this ${${project.artifactId}} which should evaluate to ${dev-service} and get the value (Dev-Service-PoD) for key "dev-service" defined in property file

Comment: I would suggest to pull up the distinction between the systems "one layer up" e.g. by introducing one Maven profile for each stage (dev, qa) which explicitely names the respective property file to use instead of another indirection by using a second property file.

Comment: Thanks Smutje, found an alternate way to fix this by using maven groovy plugin to set variable dynamically from scripts,